# There are no taxes showing on my Woocommerce, how do I show them on my website?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Since yesterday I cannot see taxes in the catalogue, cart and checkout of my store in Woocommerce anymore. I set all the correct settings but the tax table is not showing anywhere. How do I solve this? Screenshots below.

[General tax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3A1lE.png)

[Example product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDUwT.png)

[Tax options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9IE4.png)

Comment: What kind of **tax table** are you expecting? can you describe it?

Comment: Yes of course, I want to display "€ X amount - Incl. VAT and shipping". Now it only says the price and there is no suffix or 21 percentage visible.